# How can I get the Nvidia driver version programatically in x86 program?

Tags: c++, driver, gpu, nvidia

What I need is the 2 number version (e.g. 368.39) of the Nvidia drivers retrieved in a `c++` program. Using Windows 7 64b.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893481/2628257) is how to do this in 64bit applications using [NVML](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml) library from Nvidia.

However, the `nvml.dll` distributed with Nvidia drivers is 64bit only. There is no way to dynamically load this library in my 32bit program. This is assuming your computer is 64bit. I have not tested this on a 32bit machine.

So far the NVML seems to be the only library that allows retrieving this information. What other methods are there to get this if any?

Answer (score 2):

```
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    // (windows) how to get the nvidea driver version?

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #define C(a) {std::cout<<a<<std::endl;} // for easy print out to console

    template <class T> inline std::string TOSTR(const T fp){    // a macro
      std::ostringstream o;
      o.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
      o << fp;  // << ends; (null-terminator character)
      return std::string(o.str());
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #pragma comment(lib,"nvapi.lib")    // needed !

    #include <nvapi.h>  // needed !

    // you have to start nvapi:

    NvAPI_Status ret(NVAPI_OK);
    ret = NvAPI_Initialize();
    if(ret != NVAPI_OK) {
      NvAPI_ShortString string;
      NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(ret, string);
      printf("NVAPI NvAPI_Initialize: %s\n", string);
    }

    NvAPI_Status s;
    NvU32 v;    // version
    NvAPI_ShortString b;    // branch
    s = NvAPI_SYS_GetDriverAndBranchVersion(&v, b);
    if(s != NVAPI_OK) {
      NvAPI_ShortString string;
      NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(s, string);
      printf("NvAPI_SYS_GetDriverAndBranchVersion: %s\n", string);
    }   

    C("Nvidea driver version: " + TOSTR(v));    // app, console output


// ...hope i can help ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using windows since you mention ".dll"
In windows you should be able to use WMI to get any hardware information you need. For a display adapter use the Win32_VideoController WMI class it has a string field called driverversion that should have what you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This gives me the file version for the Nvidia driver as shown in the first link in the question. I need the 2 number version identifier. If there's a way to convert one to the other or find a table that relates both identifiers I would like to know too. Thanks.